# Diagonal distortion after set ROI EMGU CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have error in Image Emgu CV. It Rises after set ROT of Image. Application don't crash and work normally but image data becomes incorrect. It's look like Diagonal distortion[image: left - correct image, right - diagonal distortion]

pic 1. left - correct image, right - diagonal distortion.

Note: it occurs only in certain proportions of ROI (but I have not found explicit pattern)

Code

```
private void Process(Bitmap newColorFrame)    {
GFrame = new GestureFrame(newColorFrame.Width, newColorFrame.Height);
GFrame.OriginalFrame = newColorFrame;
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> workFrameEmguCV = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, byte>(newColorFrame);
workFrameEmguCV.ROI = GestureSystem.Property.WorkArea;
workFrameEmguCV = workFrameEmguCV.Copy();
CvInvoke.cvResetImageROI(workFrameEmguCV);
Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Byte> motionFrameEmguCV = MotionDrctr.Tracking(workFrameEmguCV);
GFrame.MotionFrame = motionFrameEmguCV;
}
```

what is it?

Comment: What about some code?

Comment: Sorry. Added code in question